# error: The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type, 'Widget', is a potentially non-nullable type

Tags: android, flutter

I'm having problems with my code inserting a "widget builder".
An error appears in the line key
`builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {`

My code that is giving this failure is:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Conversas").snapshots(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return Center(
            child: Text("Desculpe. Aconteceu algum erro de nossa parte. =(")
        ); //Center
      }

      if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
        return Center(
            child: Text("Carregando")
        ); //Center
      }

      if(snapshot.hasData) {
        return CustomScrollView(
          slivers: [
            CupertinoSliverNavigationBar(
              largeTitle: Text('Conversas'),
            ), //CupertinoSliverNavigationBar
            SliverList(
                delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
                  snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document){
                return Container();
              }).toList())) //SliverChildListDelegate, SliverList
          ],
        ); //CustomScrollView
      }
}); //StreamBuilder
```

When I try to run the app, the log that appears in the console is:

Launching lib\main.dart on SM G780G in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
lib/screens/conversas.dart:13:18: Error: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'Widget' doesn't allow null.

- 'Widget' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
  ^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1156
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 17s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return a container or sized box at the end. If no condition is met then it's null which is not a return type widget. But the method requires a widget to be returned so adding a return any widget at the end should resolve it

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Conversas").snapshots(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return Center(
            child: Text("Desculpe. Aconteceu algum erro de nossa parte. =(")
        ); //Center
      }

      if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
        return Center(
            child: Text("Carregando")
        ); //Center
      }

      if(snapshot.hasData) {
        return CustomScrollView(
          slivers: [
            CupertinoSliverNavigationBar(
              largeTitle: Text('Conversas'),
            ), //CupertinoSliverNavigationBar
            SliverList(
                delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
                  snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document){
                return Container();
              }).toList())) //SliverChildListDelegate, SliverList
          ],
        ); //CustomScrollView
      }
return SizedBox.shrink();// add this. If it doesn't meet any condition then a sized box with no size is returned
}); //
```

Comment: Oh! Very nice. Thanks, bro!